# run Backbone view template that defined in sails .ejs file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sails.js, marionette, ejs

I'm using backbone marionette with server node.js - sails.js.

I have following code in index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="header-region"></div>

    <div id="main-region" class="container">
      <p></p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/template" id="admin">
      <div > <%= name %> </div>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The template should be called here:

```
templateHelpers: {
        getData: function(){
          require(["apps/models/userRole"]);
          data = App.request("userRole:role", this);
          var compiled = _.template($("#" + data.name).html(), this);
          return compiled;
        }
},
```

But when the index.ejs being loaded(and not when I call it in the templateHelper) I'm getting an error: `name is not defined`

As I know, it should be run only when it called! or maybe there is a difference with it between `html` and `ejs`?

Comment: Is `App.request()` an async function? If so basically it's making a request call and the next line `var compiled...` runs without the return value from the async call leaving you with an undefined. You'd need to throw that in the success callback if this is the case.